# Oracle SQL "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm running some Oracle SQL and receiving the error "ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows". I understand why this error would normally be thrown, but I'm requesting exactly one row and only one row is actually being returned. *(I am unable to create an SQL Fiddle for this, as I keep receiving an error that my schema creation syntax is incorrect despite the fact that it runs successfully in SQL Plus)*

My code is below. The function creates successfully, no errors are thrown. When I try to run the verification code, however, I receive the above error. Manually running the select statement returns only one row even though the error claims more than one row is being returned. What's wrong with my code to cause this error?

The database schema:

```
create table Employee 
(
    fname varchar(15),
    minit varchar(1),
    lname varchar(15),
    ssn char(9),
    bdate date,
    address varchar(30),
    sex varchar(1)  CHECK(sex = 'M' or sex = 'F'),
    salary number   CHECK(salary >= 20000 and salary <= 100000),
    super_ssn char(9),
    dno number  DEFAULT 0,
    constraint EMPPK
        primary key(ssn),
    constraint EMPSUPERVRFK
        foreign key(super_ssn) references Employee(ssn)
            ON DELETE SET NULL
);

create table Department 
(
    dname varchar(15)   NOT NULL,
    dnumber number,
    mgr_ssn char(9)     DEFAULT '000000000',
    mgr_start_date date,
    constraint DEPTPK
        primary key(dnumber),
    constraint DEPTMGRFK
        foreign key(mgr_ssn) references Employee(ssn)
            ON DELETE SET NULL
);

insert into Employee values ('James','E','Borg','888665555','10-NOV-1937','450 Stone, Houston, TX','M',55000,null,1);
insert into Employee values ('Franklin','T','Wong','333445555','08-DEC-1955','638 Voss, Houston, TX','M',40000,'888665555',5);
insert into Employee values ('John','B','Smith','123456789','09-JAN-1965','731 Fondren, Houston, TX','M',30000,'333445555',5);
insert into Employee values ('Jennifer','S','Wallace','987654321','20-JUN-1941','291 Berry, Bellaire, TX','F',43000,'888665555',4);
insert into Employee values ('Alicia','J','Zelaya','999887777','19-JAN-1968','3321 Castle, Spring, TX','F',25000,'987654321',4);
insert into Employee values ('Ramesh','K','Narayan','666884444','15-SEP-1962','975 Fire Oak, Humble, TX','M',38000,'333445555',5);
insert into Employee values ('Joyce','A','English','453453453','31-JUL-1972','5631 Rice, Houston, TX','F',25000,'333445555',5);
insert into Employee values ('Ahmad','V','Jabbar','987987987','29-MAR-1969','980 Dallas, Houston, TX','M',25000,'987654321',4);

insert into Department values ('Research',5,'333445555','22-MAY-1988');
insert into Department values ('Administration',4,'987654321','01-JAN-1995');
insert into Department values ('Headquarters',1,'888665555','19-JUN-1981');
```

Function (created with no errors):

```
create or replace function getManagerNameDnameFunc(DNAME in department.dname%type)
    return varchar
is
    name varchar(50);
begin
    name := '';

    select e.fname || ' ' || e.lname into name from employee e, department d
    where d.dname = DNAME and d.mgr_ssn = e.ssn;

    return(name);

    exception
        when NO_DATA_FOUND then
            dbms_output.put_line('No data found');
            return(name);
end;
/
show errors
```

Test code:

```
declare
    rs varchar(10);
    pr varchar(10);
begin
    rs := 'Research';
    pr := 'Printing';
    dbms_output.put_line('Manager of Research department is ' || getManagerNameDnameFunc(rs));
    dbms_output.put_line('Manager of Printing department is ' || getManagerNameDnameFunc(pr));
end;
/
```

Exact output of `select e.fname || ' ' || e.lname from employee e, department d where d.dname = 'Research' and d.mgr_ssn = e.ssn;` (this name is what the function *should* output for the manager of the Research department):

```
E.FNAME||''||E.LNAME
-------------------------------
Franklin Wong
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include statements to populate the tables with data extracted from your database. And as a side note - you might try running both of the queries in a query tool (such as SQL*Plus). As another note - it doesn't appear that the department name is required to be unique.

Comment: Added the inserted data into the schema code, my apologies for forgetting that. I am running them in SQL*Plus and I'm getting the output that I described.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the name of the parameter to your function.  In your query, when you write

```
where d.dname = DNAME
```

I assume your intention is to compare the `dname` from the `Department` table against the `dname` that is passed in.  That is not, however, what your code is doing.  Since the right-hand identifier is unqualified, Oracle first tries to resolve it as the name of a column in one of the tables.  Since there is a `dname` column in the `department` table, that's what `dname` refers to.  So you've, in essence, coded a no-op

```
where d.dname = d.DNAME
```

A common solution is to come up with a standard convention for naming parameters and local variables that doesn't conflict with column names.  Personally, I prefix parameters with `p_` and local variables with `l_`, which is a pretty common convention.

```
create or replace function getManagerNameDnameFunc(p_dname in department.dname%type)
    return varchar
is
    name varchar(50);
begin
    select e.fname || ' ' || e.lname 
      into name from employee e, department d
     where d.dname = p_dname 
       and d.mgr_ssn = e.ssn;
```

Less commonly, you could explicitly prefix the identifier with the procedure name

```
select e.fname || ' ' || e.lname 
  into name 
  from employee e, department d
 where d.dname = getManagerNameDnameFunc.DNAME 
   and d.mgr_ssn = e.ssn;
```

Comment: Dang, it's always something really simple. This solved my problem, thank you very much!